# Python mock: mock object not updated when running multiple tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock a function calling a remote_api:

```
def get_remote_value():
    ret = make_distant_call()
    return ret > 0
```

This function is called in another function:

```
from another_file import get_remote_value

def check_remote_value():
    remote_value = get_remote_value()
    # Actually do some computation but it doesn't change the issue
    return remote_value
```

Here's my test:

```
@mock.patch('another_file.get_remote_value')
class MyTest(TestCase):
    def first_test(self, mock_get_remote_value):
        mock_get_remote_value.return_value = True
        self.assertEqual(check_remote_value(), True)

    def second_test(self, mock_get_remote_value):
        mock_get_remote_value.return_value = False
        self.assertEqual(check_remote_value(), False)
```

When I run each test on its own, it works fine. When I run the whole class, the second test fails because `get_remote_value` returns `True` and not `False`.

I'm thinking the `check_remote_value` function is still using the old mock and that's what's causing the issue. Am I right? In anyway, how can I change my test so that it runs smoothly?

I tried using the decorator on each function, using the patch context manager, to no avail. Mocking the whole `check_remote_value` is not really an option since it's the one I want to test.

Comment: I suspect you are mocking the wrong instance of `get_remote_value`. How do you import `check_remote_value` into your test script? If with something like `from mymodule import check_remote_value` you need to patch `mymodule.another_file.get_remote_value`.

Comment: @chepner I may have over-simplified my test. I'm actually testing a Django view which calls the the `check_remote_value` function. In the view I'm importing the function like this: `from mymodule.utils import check_remote_value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to patch the name that `check_remote_value` actually uses.

```
@mock.path('mymodule.utils.another_file.get_remote_value')
class MyTest(TestCase):
    def first_test(self, mock_get_remote_value):
        mock_get_remote_value.return_value = True
        self.assertEqual(check_remote_value(), True)

    def second_test(self, mock_get_remote_value):
        mock_get_remote_value.return_value = False
        self.assertEqual(check_remote_value(), False)
```

This is due to how functions look up global values. `check_remote_value` has a reference to the global scope defined in `mymodule.utils`, not your test script, so that is where it looks when it needs to look up `get_remote_value`.

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion :p Thanks a lot!